# Mi buscador ajax no encuentra nada

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

buen dia tengo una duda acerca de un buscador en tiempo real el cual menciona que no esta definida la variable pero cuando la agrego el `$nombrevariale=$_GET['nombrevariavle'];`
me sigue saliendo ese mismo error y no se por que

Autocomplete Search with Bootstrap Typeahead

Search Name
Search Name....

> Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginPHP\buscar.php on line 52
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginPHP\buscar.php:53 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginPHP\buscar.php on line 53

Código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Buscar en el contenido de una tabla</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
return $.get('buscar.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
data = $.parseJSON(data);
return process(data);
});
},
showHintOnFocus:'all'
});
});
    </script>
 
 
</head>
 
<body>


<div class="container">
<h2>Autocomplete Search with Bootstrap Typeahead</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
<br/>
<label>Search Name</label>
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Name....">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



  
            <?php
            $servername = "127.0.0.1:4473";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "usuarios";
            $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM perm WHERE usuario LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' LIMIT 20";
            $resultset = mysql_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysql_error($conn));
            $json = array();
            while( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
            $json[] = $rows["usuario"];
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            ?>
```

Comment: le pose mysqli_query y me salieron mas errores

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, deja de usar las funciones mysql_query(), etc. Usa PDO en su lugar para acceder a las bases de datos. Es igual de sencillo, no tiene mucha mayor complejidad.

Lo segundo, veo que devuelves lo que se supone que obtienes de la BD mediante la sentencia
echo json_encode($json). Bien, lo primero que debes hacer es asegurarte que ese json_encode se ha ejecutado correctamente, quizás precisamente por no haber podido formar correctamente el objeto JSON no te devuelva nada.

Para ello, haz lo siguiente: (por ejemplo, codificalo como quieras)

$respuesta = json_encode($json);

Ahora debes llamar a las funciones json_last_error() y json_last_error_msg() que te proporcionan respectivamente el estado y el mensaje asociado a ese estado de la última operación que se haya echo de codificación/Descodificación a JSON

$lasterrorcode = json_last_error();
$lasterrormessage = json_last_error_msg();

comprueba el valor de $lasterrorcode, si no es cero, es que ha habido un error. En la variable $lasterrormessage tendrás el mensaje de error. Esta misma información la tienes en el manual de PHP.

Si el valor de  $lasterrorcode es cero, el Json se ha codificado bien, ya podrías hacer
un echo $respuesta, sino devuelve nada será por otro motivo.

Recomendación: Siempre comprueba que las cosas se han hecho correctamente. Te dejo una clase estática que he hecho, que reemplaza a la función json_encode, que sirve para que ademas de devolver la respuesta, cosido a esa respuesta, te manda el codigo de error y el mensaje de esa operación de codificación.

````
<?php 
class JSON 
{

   public static function encode($data)
   {
       $jsonencode = json_encode($data); 
       $lasterrorcode = json_last_error();
       $lasterrormessage = json_last_error_msg();

       $respuesta = json_decode($jsonencode, true);
       $respuesta["errorCode"] = $lasterrorcode;
       $respuesta["errorMessage"] = $lasterrormessage;

       return json_encode($respuesta); 
   }

} // JSON
```
en lugar de hacer $respuesta = json_encode($json) escribe
$respuesta = JSON::encode($json)
te devolverá igualmente un objeto JSON con este formato:

{"los datos obtenidos", "errorCode":"Aqui el codigo de error", "errorMessage" : "aqui el mensaje de error"}

Como ves, obtienes la respuesta y cosida a ella el estado de la operación de codificación.
La clase la acabo de hacer, es muy mejorable, eso ya te lo dejo a tí.

Un saludo
````

Comment: Si claro, si no lo argumento por sencillez, lo que pretendo es que si no usa PDO por que no sabe como va, pues decirle que es igual de sencillo, que no tenga miedo de usarlo. Por supuesto que no recomiendo usar metodología obsoleta

Comment: Lo mismo puedo decir de tu primera respuesta no?? Yo intento solucionar su duda concreta, ayudarle en lo que ha preguntado, no explicarle otra cosa.

Comment: Está claro que estás teniendo un mal día! jajaj Anda vete a descansar, que te hace falta!!  relájate un ratito, a ver si se te pasa la tontería

Comment: oigan pero necesito resolver mi duda

Comment: quiero crear un buscador en tiempo real o bien uno antiguo con boton

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando mysqli. Ya que mysql ya no se usa

Así:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "127.0.0.1:4473";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "usuarios";
    $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM perm WHERE usuario LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' LIMIT 20";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $json = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $json[] = $rows["usuario"];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
    ?>
```